# Finding the divisors of every content of a list by checking the contents of another list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to write a code which does the following:

- Inputs a list of numbers
- Checks if every split digit of the number is a divisor of the number or not
- Prints the number of divisors

Here's the incomplete code I have written:

```
n = int(input('Number of subsequences: '))
num_input = []
split_nums = []
counter = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    num_input.append(input())
    split_nums.append(list(map(int,str(num_input[i]))))
```

**Problem:** I have created two separated lists, one is the input numbers (num_input) and the other is the split digits of the numbers of input (split_nums). How can I now determine what the code should do, in order to check if the contents of split_nums are divisors for contents of num_input?

**You can take a look at what I more precisely desire my code to do with examples in here:** https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-digits/problem *(No sign-up or log-in required)*

Any tips, solutions or algorithms is in advance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create 2 lists. Just create a function to do the work. Call this function for each input.

```
def check_digits(n):   
    count = 0  # Number of matches
    n_copy = n  # n is modified in loop
    while n:
        d = n % 10  # Get digit
        if d != 0 and n_copy % d == 0:
            count += 1
        n //= 10   # Remove digit
    return count
```

Comment: I see! My way is for sure not a encouraged... But I couldn't come up with any other idea. Your way is by far better! Thanks :)